# Display videos in website, working in Visual Studio debugger but not in Release version

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web

I am working on a website that has to show many videos. I do this with this code:

```js
<video id="myVideo" width="432" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
    <source src=@Model[1].VideoPath type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

@Model[1].VideoPath is the path for the video (this is using ASP.NET-MVC). During debugging this was working fine, with a relative path (such as "../../videosFolder/videoName.mp4").

Now for release it is not working any more. In case I got the relative path wrong I switched to an absolute path ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot...\videoName.mp4").

I have made sure that the video exists, the website itself is printing the path and it is the correct one. The application pool is running with a user identity with full privileges, and all folders from inetpub forward are also readable for anyone... so why is this not working now?

Update:
I have been asked to upload the "live HTML". I am not sure I am doing this right, but examining the element I get this (again, the path is correct):

```
<video id="parentVideo" width="432" height="240" controls="" autoplay="" loop=""> <source src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\correctPath\myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Can you update w/ what the HTML looks like live (razor compiled) on the release version?

Comment: I sure can! But... I am not entirely sure what it is you want or how to provide you with it. Sorry, I really have such little experience with websites!

Comment: This is what I get if I examine the element in the website (hopefully this is what you need?): <video id="parentVideo" width="432" height="240" controls="" autoplay="" loop="">
                <source src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\correctPath\myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>

Comment: I was wondering how to do this right, I obviously want to load videos from the server! Could you point to a link where they explain how to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\correctPath\myVideo.mp4"` is your problem. You can't access files on the end user's local machine due to security restrictions (even if you could, how would you know the path, and how could you assume the file existed??).

This value should be a http URL pointing to where the video is accessible online,
 e.g. `src="https://www.example.com/videos/myVideo.mp4"` (presumably, on your server?).

This principle applies to everything, not just videos (i.e. in a web page you must always reference a resource via URL, never via a disk path).

You may also need to configure the mime type / file extension settings in IIS to ensure all the file types you are serving are supported by the server.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you have correctly identified the source of the problem! Could you perhaps point me in a direction so that I can figure out the way to do it correctly?

Comment: You have to write it as a URL, as I showed above. I can't tell you exactly what the URL should be because I don't know the structure of your webserver. If I had to _guess_ based on the file path you gave, and a standard IIS setup, then probably your URL is going to be something like `http://www.yourdomainname.com/correctPath/myVideo.mp4`, but that's purely speculative. Your server might be set up completely differently. You need to check where the root folder is for your application, compared to where the video file is stored, and then construct the URL relative to those things.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful place for me to start working. I'll see if I can make it work...

Comment: Assuming the videos are stored in a location which is actually accessible to the webserver via an IIS site or virtual directory (and in a basic/standard setup, anything in the wwwroot folder, like you've got, would be accessible to the webserver), then you can definitely do it.

Comment: I get an error: GET (url) 404. The url seems right (the url is ".../folder/video.mp4", and going to ".../folder" shows the video files there (I have enabled directory browsing). Am I missing any obvious step?

Comment: it should be `..` not `...`. Is that folder correct relative to your application's root? Does `video.mp4` exist in that folder? Before you said you were using `myVideo.mp4` as an example. TBH it's difficult to help, I'm fighting blind because I can't see your server. The _principle_ of my answer is correct (i.e. you must use HTTP), the specifics of your individual file locations is not really the point. If you don't understand webserver folder structures sufficiently to figure it out, ask someone who can access your server to help you, and/or do some research to understand how it works.

Comment: It seems like there is something else missing. I have tried with an image, and that works. So I am sure the url for the video is also correct. However, the image works but the video still complains "not found"...

Comment: maybe the mime type / file extension combo for mp4 is not registered in IIS. Anyway please accept the answer, because if you got it to work with an image, that proves the concept.

Comment: Well, the video is not working yet, so I don't have an answer for the question yet. Your reply is indeed useful and points to part of the problem (which is why I have already upvoted it). Don't worry, I will accept the answer when I am able to make it work.

Comment: Your server config for videos is not part of the question or directly related to the issue. The original issue was that you didn't use the correct _protocol_ to access the files. The actual nature of the file you're accessing is not relevant to that. Like said, it works with pictures so clearly the problem is this specific file, not the way I suggested that you change your _general approach_ to creating links to your files. These are two separate considerations.

Comment: I disagree. In fact, I believe at some point Visual Studio was creating the correct url for me (when I was working with relative paths). Because this was failing I switched to the local path, which you pointed out as incorrect. But the question is why the video works in Visual Studio and not in IIS (that's basically the title of the question). It looks like it might be related to your previous comment about mimes. I am working on that now, just give me some time.

Comment: It was the missing mime type in IIS! (Extension .mp4, type video/mp4). If you just add that to your answer I will accept it! And thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have added a couple of clarifications to the answer, based on this discussion, thanks. Glad you got it working.